# iphone - PushViewController does not work With Reveal Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I am creating an iphone application, where i have number of grid views in a main view controller class. So, i want when i select a grid cell from main view, should load a Reveal controller. The layout looks like

[image]    [image]

I have the following code in my Main View Controller.

```
-(void) gridView:(UzysGridView *)gridView didSelectCell:(UzysGridViewCell *)cell   
atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
if (index == 0){
    FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc]  
    init];

    RightViewController *rightViewController = [[RightViewController alloc] init];

    UINavigationController *frontNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
    initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

    SWRevealViewController *mainRevealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithRearViewController:nil 
    frontViewController:frontNavigationController];

    mainRevealController.delegate = self;

    self.revealController.rightViewController = rightViewController;

    self.revealController = mainRevealController;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.revealController animated:YES];
 }
```

here in main view controller .h file,

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) SWRevealViewController *revealController;
```

Also i have declare SWRevealViewControllerDelegate. Problem is that this self.revealController doesn't load/show. I have tried with App Delegate also, but nothing works.
thanks.

Comment: The most common possible problems with this code:
Does self have a navigationController?
Secondly you set self.revealController.rightViewController = rightViewController; and then you set the self.revealController to something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it: Use the below code..

```
    -(void) gridView:(UzysGridView *)gridView didSelectCell:(UzysGridViewCell *)cell   
    atIndex:(NSUInteger)index {

    if (index == 0){
    FrontViewController *frontViewController = [[FrontViewController alloc] 
    init];

    myNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] 
    initWithRootViewController:frontViewController];

    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [[SWRevealViewController alloc] 
    initWithRearViewController:nil frontViewController:myNavigationController];

    revealController.delegate = self;

    RightViewController *rightViewController = 
    [[RightViewController alloc] init];

    rightViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];

    revealController.rightViewController = rightViewController;

    self.viewController1=revealController;

    [self presentViewController:self.viewController1 animated:YES completion:nil];
                   }
    }
```

And in Class.h file

```
     @property(nonatomic, strong) UINavigationController *myNavigationController;

     @property(nonatomic, strong) SWRevealViewController *viewController1;
```

Comment: Thanks, It's Working